# Error: mongoose.model is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, webpack

I'm following along in a few different MEAN tutorials, and I'm getting hung up on something that none of the tutorials seem to encounter. I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.model is not a function
```

I tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling everything, and that didn't help. What am I missing? I'm using Webpack to load my modules. Could that have anything to do with this issue?

Here's my model:

**./app/authentication/user.model.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and the following mongoose config file:

**./server/config/mongoose.js**

```
'use strict';

var config = require('./environment');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
    var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
        process.exit(-1);
    });

    require('../../app/authentication/user.model');

    return db;
};
```

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using? Note that the version which is installed for your project is managed by your project's package.json 
run `npm install mongoose@latest` to force the latest version

Comment: I'm using 4.4.12, which is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: the problem with call back use this line

Comment: I just tried that, and I'm still getting the same error, sadly.

Comment: I'm using Webpack to load my modules. Could that have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: @jrsowles did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004659/using-webpack-with-mongoose-mongoose-model-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my mongoose and it worked fine:

`mongoose": "^4.13.12",
"mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",`

Comment: I am fairly certain we have the same problem since I ran into this after bumping mongoose version to 5+. The issue is that the docs previous set mongoose like so `let mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.mongoURI,config.mogoOptions);`. 

In 5+ this this needs to be 
`let mongoose = require('mongoose');` `mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI,config.mogoOptions);` 

`connect` needs to be called separately since it doesn't return the mongoose object in 5+.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    lastName:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    email:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    password:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I hope this helps someone. It took me a lot of time to figure it out.